# tool to capture video from desktop activities

Tags: video

I've a website. I want to provide users a video on how to use it.

Is there any tool, which can capture whatever I do in my website and convert it as a video?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is a duplicate but if you can show that it is not we'll also need more information; what OS, and what features you are looking for.

Comment: No, it is duplicate. I could not search for it appropriately

Comment: @NickWilde Not a duplicate. The other question has a requirement for capturing mouse movements, which a software posted here doesn't have (but is still a great sw).

Comment: @AmitJoki: Do you need mouse movements or not? Or any is fine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GIFcam](http://blog.bahraniapps.com/?page_id=21) allows to record videos as GIF. It is very simple to add text or a cursor.

[image: GIFcam example]

In the end, it is possible to convert the GIF to an htlm5 video. There are services such as [GFYcat](http://gfycat.com/), or plugins in Python such as [moviePy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/). Here is [a walkthrough](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/01/23/making-animated-gifs-from-video-files-with-python/) with using moviePy.

Comment: SO , I can capture the activities using GIFCam?

Comment: Well, yes, you can.